# Android LibGDX shader compatibility

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX for Android.
I have my fragment and vertex shaders as follow

**Fragment shader:**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOW lowp
#define MED mediump
#define HIGH highp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define MED
#define LOW
#define HIGH
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform vec2 oneOverResolution;

vec2 frgCOverRes;

void main() {
   frgCOverRes = gl_FragCoord.xy*oneOverResolution.xy;
   frgCOverRes.y = -frgCOverRes.y+1;

   vec4 c = texture2D(u_texture, frgCOverRes);

   gl_FragColor = c;
}
```

**vertex shader:**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

**But** I read that **highp** is not compatible with some devices.

And also it is not been used (mediump, lowp is also not been used).

So I'm going to change the fragment shader to the following code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform vec2 oneOverResolution;

vec2 frgCOverRes;

void main() {
   frgCOverRes = gl_FragCoord.xy*oneOverResolution.xy;
   frgCOverRes.y = -frgCOverRes.y+1.0;

   vec4 c = texture2D(u_texture, frgCOverRes);

   gl_FragColor = c;
}
```

I'm using 9 as the minSdkVersion.

I have tested this code in Emulator and in my phone (huaweii j6ii).

But have doubts with other devices.

**Deos this fragment shader compatible with all device?**

Comment: `texture2D` is deprecated but you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this fragment shader compatible with all device?

It should work for any device supporting OpenGL ES 2.0 onwards.

One observation is that doing this per pixel is more expensive than it needs to be:

```
frgCOverRes = gl_FragCoord.xy * oneOverResolution.xy;
frgCOverRes.y = -frgCOverRes.y + 1.0;
```

Why not just upload the correct texture coordinate in the first place? The y-flip should be predictable. (Failing that it would be better to correct it in the vertex shader per vertex, not per fragment).